# How can i pass a variable from a loop (HandleBar template) to Express helper To get some result?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, handlebars.js

I want to pass a ID to fetch the results such as Status, From Handlebar template to express helper

I have tried HBS helper but as far my searched results show me that i can't do any SYNC in hbs helper until i use any express helper. Like as, app.use(some express helper).

> hbs template

```
{{#result}}
  {{need to call and get value from express helper}}
{{/result}}
```

But i want use that function only once a time not on every single request. I don't know that, my tried method was right or any other better way to come out with the best results.

Here some Images:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rei4d.png)[Route.js file]
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cshi.png)[View.hbs File]

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm assuming you are passing variables into your template from express controller that is rendering the html page.
2. If the above is true, you can just pass in the function from the controller as if you would a variable to the html page.

Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: Ya. I understand your method and I did that. But actual problem is I got some table join and which is very difficult. I got two table 1)roomInfo 2) roomMember. And a page which is full of room information where (in hbs Template) in loop a column name called STATUS which is basically a status field to see logged in user is in the room or not. Or request accepted or not (just a tooltip status). So it's hard to join those two tables to get my desire result. Like as,  I can call a php function from a view page to get that result. Is their anyway to do like that. I think you understand. Thank you.

Comment: I added some picture. I think you will understand. Please review those images and help me to find out the right way to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In Express file you declare the route and declare the error variable

```
app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
      return res.status(404).render("login",{stuff:"Password is Incorrect!!"});
});
```

In HBS Login file simply write variable name

```
{{ stuff }}
```